# pass variable to xquery xpath attribute query

Tags: variables, xpath, attributes, range, xquery

I'm trying to perform a simple xquery operation to return a list of nodes whose attributes match a range of numbers

I have tried the following...

XML Source:

```
    <cars>
     <car id="1">Ford</car>
     <car id="2">Mazda</car>
     <car id="3">Toyota</car>
     <car id="4">Lexus</car>
    </cars>
```

XQuery:

```
    let $i := 1
    return //car[@id="{$i}"]
```

but it does not work. It seems so simple, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's even easier than that:

```
let $range := 2 to 3
return //car[@id = $range]
```

Result:

```
<car id="2">Mazda</car>
<car id="3">Toyota</car>
```